# Bigquery unable to load data Date value or Time stamp value format wrong

Tags: google-bigquery, bigtable, bigdata

```
1.Error while uploading CSV , where Data format is '0000-00-00' &&  timestamp has '0000-00-00 00:00:00' value.
2.The Datatype is DATE, TIMESTAMP as Follows.
```

[image]
[image]
Am i missing any ignore checkbox. Tried to ignore all the errors, but instead of loading all data bigquery ignored the date format rows and uploaded only allowed ones.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8GTP.png)

Tried with null values , Unable to do it, had no choice , replaced the DATE with '1969-01-01'  and Timestamp to '1969-01-01 00:00:00'. I was able to upload the data.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The lower bound on valid dates is `0001-01-01`; the [data types page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#date-type) has more information about valid ranges for various types. One option is to load the values as type `STRING` instead, then apply a function such as `SAFE_CAST(string_date_col AS DATE)` to transform the values to `DATE` type. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(string_date_col, string_timestamp_col),
  SAFE_CAST(string_date_col AS DATE) AS date_col,
  SAFE_CAST(string_timestamp_col AS TIMESTAMP) AS timestamp_col 
FROM MyTableWithStrings;
```

As a self-contained example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH MyTableWithStrings AS (
  SELECT 1 AS x, '0000-00-00' AS string_date_col, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AS string_timestamp_col UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS x, '2017-03-07' AS string_date_col, '2017-03-07 12:34:56' AS string_timestamp_col
)
SELECT
  * EXCEPT(string_date_col, string_timestamp_col),
  SAFE_CAST(string_date_col AS DATE) AS date_col,
  SAFE_CAST(string_timestamp_col AS TIMESTAMP) AS timestamp_col 
FROM MyTableWithStrings;
```

This replaces the invalid date and timestamp strings with NULL values.

Comment: For now i made it as 1969-01-01 and 1969-01-01 00:00:00,  and data got uploaded, would it be a good idea to Type cast every row , As it almost 2M records. Please correct me.

Comment: The Problem i was unable to load the data itself, while creating the table. I have updated the Question regarding null values for DATE and TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

There are not enough controls for Load API to control behavior on invalid `DATE`/`TIMESTAMP` values - you can file Feature Request to BigQuery Issue Tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149.
In the meantime the workaround is to use federated query over CSV as described in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources#table_definitions_based_on_csv_source_files and use `SAFE_CAST` function as described in Elliott's answer.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36043493 mailed the issue . For now i might have to change the invalid DATE/TIMESTAMP to above .